# Magento integration with third party application

Tags: web-services, magento

I am newbee in magento and i have got task to integrate third party application (built in Dot Net) with magento. Though i know that magneto provide web services which we can integrate with third party application and retrieve all eCommerce records from magento to third party application.

But in my case i have strange requirement where i have to integrate third party app into magento and use only shopping cart functionality of magento.Here catch is that i dont want to create product or catalogue in magento but i have to fetch all data from .net application.
and after successful shopping, send back invoice no to .net app.

Can anybody tell me is it possible to integrate third party app and fetch all its data in magento .

In nut shell i would say that, is it possible to consume third party application web services in magento.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It will require a lot of custom development though.

Comment: what kind of custom  development is required. Do i need to develope  some addtional magento extension which will take third party web services as input parameter and process it inside magento and send back its output to third party app.

Comment: @Vish Like Cags said its true. You need to do that. A little easier way will be keep data in both applications Magento as well as .NET and Use Magento API to facilitate data to third party API... If the magento will pull data and write data to the Third party API then API will be of little HELP and you have to write custom modules.